How to connect woocommerce with React using Auth1.0?
I am trying to integrate my e-commerce platform into my React application. But I am not able to connect. I am always getting errors.
This time CORS error is coming. I am not able to understand how to resolve this.
Please review my code and let me know if anyone can help me.
Here is the working code available for this.
This API is working fine in Postman.
https://9000-monospace-my-test-app-1715420758185.cluster-3g4scxt2njdd6uovkqyfcabgo6.cloudworkstations.dev/?monospaceUid=683162
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import './App.css'
import OAuth from 'oauth-1.0a';
import axios from 'axios';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';


function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const customer_key = '*******************************';
  const consumer_key = '*******************************';


  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const oauth = OAuth({
      consumer: {
        key: customer_key,
        secret: consumer_key
      },
      signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      hash_function(base_string, key) {
        return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key));
      }
    });

    const request_data = {
      url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v3/products',
      method: 'GET'
    };

    const authorization = oauth.authorize(request_data);

    const headers = oauth.toHeader(authorization);
    
    axios.get(request_data.url, { headers })
      .then(response => {
        setPosts(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching posts:', error);
      });
  }, []);



  return (
    <>
     <div>
      <h1>Sample OAuth 1.0a Authenticated API Data</h1>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>
            <h2>{post.title}</h2>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App


Any solution is appreciated!
